# Code Coverage - Moq testing for Property

Tags: moq

Can anyone help me how can i do code coverage for below property using Moq -

```
public class Test
{

  public IEmployee Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return TypeFactory.Resolve(typeof(IEmployee)) as IEmployee;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't do code coverage with Moq.

You may setup the property with MoQ, to use a component depending on this property with .setupget();

Or if you want to test the getter itself(cover it by a test), make a test that calls for it. Than you'll ned to setup with MoQ the component it depends on - TypeFactory in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I tried below code -  var mock = new Mock<Test>();mock.SetUp(fake => fake.Employee).Returns(); But i am not sure what i need to keep in Returns or not sure how can i build IEmployee object as i am new to Moq testing.Thanks once again

Comment: @Beginner First of all, you should take a break and think about that you actually want to test.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus I want to test the above Employee property - I mean if IEmployee object is null then how can i Compare values using Assert.Excuse me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks

Comment: If you use the code you've write, you're mocking the Test class, that means you're testing external component.